# A Question from complex variable

Tags: analyticity

Show that an analytic function with constant modulus is itself a constant

Comment: See [Maximum Modulus Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle). It is impossible to know what you need in addition without you being more detailed in your question.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Please be more detailed in your question and show your attempt. This will help us to give the best answers at your level and form that you will learn most. You can edit your post to add this.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Write $f = u+iv$. If $|f| = 0$ then $f = 0$ and there's nothing to do. Otherwise, $u²+v² = c²$ for some constant $c > 0$. Differentiate implicitly w.r.t. $x$ and $y$ and use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to conclude that $u_x = u_y = v_x = v_y \equiv 0$.